# pyparsing with ebnf and whitespaces

Tags: python, pyparsing, ebnf

I'm using http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/file/view/ebnf.py to convert my ebnf definition.

ebnf def looks like this:

```
TEST = A, SPACE, A;

A = "AA" | "BB";
SPACE = " ";
```

if I load the file and try to parse a string like:

```
e = ebnf.parse(ebnf_file)
e['TEST'].leaveWhitespace().parseString('AA BB') # same without leaveWhitespace()
```

I get:

```
ParseException: Expected " " (at char 3), (line:1, col:4)
```

Does anybody have an ideas/solutions?

Comment: Pyparsing is no longer hosted on wikispaces.com. Go to https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `leaveWhitespace()` has to be applied to the original whitespace-containing tag, so try the following:

```
e = ebnf.parse(ebnf_file)
e['SPACE'] = e['SPACE'].leaveWhitespace()
e['TEST'].parseString('AA BB')
```